How to add a new type to an already declared variable for a legacy API without inheritance?
Example:
functionA () {
  TypeA o = TypeA{"abcd"};
  functionB.(o);
}

Now assuming I modified functionB to accept a new TypeB.
I want to achieve similar to
functionA () {
  if (useA) {
    TypeA o = TypeA{"abcd"};
  } else {
    TypeB o = TypeB{"abcd"};
  }
  functionB.(o);
}

Because o is not declared outside the if-else structure, it throws a non-existence error. What would be the least intrusive way to modify the code to fix this error?
update：

if (useA) functionB(TypeA{...}); else functionB(TypeB{...});

functionB is inside a big try-block. Could not copy them twice.

if (useA) functionB(TypeA{...}); else functionB(TypeB{...});?

Is functionB overloaded to accept either TypeA or TypeB?

Overloaded or templated could work for FunctionB. If possible, I'd prefer to template and reduce duplication.

Are you, by any chance, using this useA  as a constant throughout the app? Maybe you just want to typedef MyType to either A or B, and use this throughout the app?

@Yksisarvinen Yes.

@ChristianStieber It's not a constant, just a local variable.
